# Hiding the closest element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some [jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/P6GEC/6/) to hide content on an index page.

the commented out code in the fiddle is what i have at the moment - but it hides all content divs if any toggle link is clicked.

### HTML

```
<div>
  <h1>Dogs</h1>
  <a class="toggle_group_name">∆</a>
</div>

<div class="group_name">
    Dogs do this, that and something
</div>

<div>
  <h1>Cats</h1>
  <a class="toggle_group_name">∆</a>
</div>

<div class="group_name">
    Cats do this, that and something different
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('.toggle_group_name').click(function() {
        $(this).parents("div").find('.group_name').toggle();
    });
});
```

I want only the class immediately following the toggle link to be hidden/shown, but can't get it working.  Have tried using `parents`, `nextAll`, and various other methods from similar examples I've found on SO, but so far nothing has worked.

Comment: Please provide relevant code

Comment: Side note: to comment code in javascript do not use `<!-- -->`. Use `//` for single-line, `/* */` for multi-line. Using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target element is not sibling or parent of the clicked element, it's next sibling of the clicked element's parent, so `.parents()` and `.nextAll()` methods are not useful in this case, you can use `.closest()`/`parent()` and `.next()` methods:

```
$(this).closest('div') // closest parent div of the clicked element 
       .next('.group_name') // it's next .group_name sibling
       .toggle();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xUgG5/

Comment: +1 Although i would recommend him to wrap the groups for a better coding technique.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work in your fiddle:

```
$(function() {
  $('.toggle_group_name').click(function() {
    $(this).parents("div").next('.group_name').toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use first().

http://jsfiddle.net/P6GEC/9/

```
$(function () {
    $('.toggle_group_name').click(function () {
        $('.group_name').first().toggle();
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: that only hides the first element regardless of which toggle is clicked